# Application_Start not called in global.asax. Why?

Tags: asp.net, application-start

In my global.asax I have the following code:

```
public static bool Was = false;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Was = true;
}
```

When I open a page and look at the `Was` variable, it's still `false`. What gives? (Note: the variable isn't used anywhere else, I made it just for this test case)

**Update:** <s>I just found out that my whole `global.asax` file is getting ignored. How can this be?</s>

**Update 2:** Sorry, it does get into play after all. But there's extra weirdness there. So much extra weirdness, that I've opened [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707835/when-does-net-check-for-assembly-dependancies) for that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the problem was that I had not installed Visual J# redist which is required by my app. However the manifestation of this problem was really weird. I've opened another question for that:

[When does .net check for assembly dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707835/when-does-net-check-for-assembly-dependancies)

In essence I guess the lesson is: when your application lacks some dependant assembly, don't expect it to fail outright. Expect some method calls to start throwing `FileNotFoundException`.